# React hook not updating the state within the hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a hooks which has 3 functions:

- Delete data
- Get data
- Update data

These functions will be used in different places in my app and so I create a React hooks for them that goes as follows:

```js
export function useData(): UseDataHook {
  const [data, setDtata] = React.useState<string | null>(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    data ? localStorage.setItem("data-key", data) : localStorage.removeItem("data-key")
  }, data)

  function deleteData(): void {
    setData("")
  }

  function getData(): void {
    return data
  }

  function updateData(data: string): void {
    console.log("updating data...")
    setData(data)
  }

  return {
    deleteData,
    getData,
    updateData
  }
}
```

Whenever updateData is called, I can see the console log just fine, but the data state doesn't update (as proven by the fact I am getting null constantly at the routes component, where I will ultimately use the data for auth in private route wrappers:

```js
const data = useData().getData()

console.log(data) //null
```

Any ideas as to why my state is not updating as I expect it to?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo here or in real code, but your setState in this code is called setDtata, also in you console.log("updating data..."), if you log data, do you get a string or null?

Comment: OK. Where do you check the `data` value? You didn't return `data` in Hook

Comment: I retrun data in the getData function, which is returned in the hook

Comment: @kianjalilian sorry yes that's just a typo on the writeup - if i log the incoming data string it shows up just fine

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in how the data is being updated.

- First, there is a typo while declaring the `data` and `setData` using `useState`

```
// This line should be
const [data, setDtata] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

// changed to following
const [data, setData] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
```

- Second, `useEffect` hook takes 2 arguments, one is the callback function and the other is an **array of dependencies**

```
// This should be
useEffect(() => {
    data
      ? localStorage.setItem("data-key", data)
      : localStorage.removeItem("data-key");
  }, data);

// changed to the following 
useEffect(() => {
    data
      ? localStorage.setItem("data-key", data)
      : localStorage.removeItem("data-key");
  }, [data]);
```

You can check the updated example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-magic-number-hs1es?file=/src/useData.tsx).

Comment: Apologies - these are just typos in my write up. I changed some variables names for security reasons etc. In my actual code, the array is there and the setData function is correctly named

Comment: @clev no worries, then the issue was in the `useEffect` hook where you were passing `data` instead of `[data]` as dependencies.